# Azure Functions - grouping messages from Azure Service Bus

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

When you have to handle a great amount of messages would be great group them to optimize the performance (but stay within the message lock duration).

For example, if for each message you have to call an external service (elasticsearch?) for the performance would be great group 1000 requests to the external service into one.

But this grouping should be handled by the Azure Function because if you group the messages by yourself: the messages are successfully read from the service bus and you are out from the message lock duration period.
In other words, if something goes wrong during the processing the entire group of message us lost, you cannot automatically deadletter them.

Can we configure the [Azure Functions bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to receive a group of message instead of one message at time?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @SeanFeldman thanks for the comment, I thought the question was implicit.

Comment: It's better to be explicit 

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Azure Service Bus trigger to receive a batch.

```
[FunctionName("TriggerBatch")]
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("<queue_name>", Connection = "<connection_name>")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
    ILogger logger)
{
    foreach (ServiceBusReceivedMessage message in messages)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Function triggered to process a message with body: {message.Body}");
        logger.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTime={message.EnqueuedTime}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not sure I can do this in python

Comment: It depends wherever Python SDK support this option for the Azure Service Bus trigger.